# Error: Protocol JSON API error running Lighthouse with TestCafe Server

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe, lighthouse

I am trying to write code that will spin up a TestCafe Server, log into an authenticated page, navigate to the page I want, and then execute Lighthouse against that page.

Here is my testcafeServer.js file:

`const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
  .then((tc) => {
    testcafe = tc;
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

    return runner.src(['test_lightHouse.js']).browsers(['chrome']).run();
  })
  .then((failedCount) => {
    console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
    testcafe.close();
  });`

Here is my test_lighthouse.js file:

`` import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
var fs = require('fs');

const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');

fixture`LightHouse Test`.page(
  'MY-SPECIFIC-URL'
);

test(`Generate Light House Result `, async (t) => {
  //Specific code to navigate to a certain page
  const auditResult = await lighthouse(
    'MY-CURRENT-URL-I-WANT-TO-TEST',
    {
      logLevel: 'info',
      output: 'html',
      port: 1337, //I am getting this port # from the TestCafe server I am standing up locally - might be wrong
    }
  );

  // Write data in 'Output.txt' .
  fs.writeFile('mynewfile3.html', auditResult, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });

  console.log(auditResult);
}); ``

When executing this code, I get the following error:

`` ✖ Generate Light House Result

   1) Error: Protocol JSON API error (list), status: 404

      Browser: Chrome 80.0.3987.163 / macOS 10.15.4

         102 |                return resolve({message: data});
         103 |              }
         104 |              return reject(e);
         105 |            }
         106 |          }
       > 107 |          reject(new Error(`Protocol JSON API error (${command}), status: ${response.statusCode}`));
         108 |        });
         109 |      });
         110 |
         111 |      // This error handler is critical to ensuring Lighthouse exits cleanly even when Chrome crashes.
         112 |      // See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/8583. ``

What is going wrong?  Why does this constantly happen?  Is Lighthouse just not meant to work with TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no simple way to integrate lighthouse with TestCafe. Please track the following issue in the TestCafe repository to be notified of our results: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3493.

Also, you can try the approach shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55447097/10684943, but it may work incorrectly with authentication pages.